# When to use ~たい for things such as 食べたい？

Tags: grammar, conjugations

What are the grammar rules for making verbs into "to want" form? 
ie 食べたい.

I want to be able to say "I want to visit hokkaido next summer."
ie 今度の夏休みに北海度に行きたいです。
is this correct?

Comment: I think although  今度 is acceptable, 来年{らいねん} would be more commonly chosen... but yes, that's a correctly written sentence. Basically whenever you "want to (do something)", using ~たい is the simplest way to express this. Why did you doubt your understanding of it?

Comment: 北海度じゃなくて北海**道**ね・・

Comment: 今度 is fine, it just doesn't mean "next year", so it can be next summer this year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's correct.

たい verbal auxiliary goes after the 連用形 of a verb:

書く →　書き　→　書きたい

食べる　→　食べ　→　食べたい